# C: Regular Expression does not match floating point literals

Tags: c, regex

I'm writing a simple script to match floating points literals, only `+123.23`, `-123.23` or `123.23` etc should be matched, so I don't match those `-1.0e-10` form. So my expression is as simple as: `[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+` which will capture the sign, digits, dot and fraction for me optionally. And my C validation looks like:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+", 0);
if (reti) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex of floating literals\n");
    exit(1);
}

char * testString = "-87.21";
reti = regexec(&regex, testString, 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti) {
    printf("%s \n", testString);
}
```

However, the value of reti is 1, which means my regex on test string "-87.21" failed. I tested my regex on regexr.com, it matches "-87.21", So I don't really know what happens here. Is there anyone can help?

Comment: @chux No, it's not the issue.

Comment: If you want to match only floating point numbers, then the period `.` must be required, not optional.

Comment: @DYZ: period is optional in floating point literals. However at least one digit either before or after the period is mandatory. OP's regex fails to match the valid `0.` or similar.

Comment: @R.. Without a period, how do you know if it's an FP literal or an integer literal?

Comment: @dyz floating-constant needs either a fractional-constant (.) or exponent-part (e,E,p)

Comment: @chux Sure, but the OP explicitly said he does not want exponentials.

Comment: @DYZ neither did OP say code need to distinguish  FP literal or an integer literal, just match floating point literals.

Comment: @chux I said "_*If* you want to match only floating point numbers..._". Did  you actually read my comment before commenting on it?

Comment: @Dyz [My comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821820/c-regular-expression-does-not-match-floating-point-literals?noredirect=1#comment72755980_42821820) was addressing [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821820/c-regular-expression-does-not-match-floating-point-literals?noredirect=1#comment72755781_42821820).  I had not read the other comment in context to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `REG_EXTENDED` flag when calling `regcomp` or else adapt your regex to be compatible with POSIX BRE (Basic Regular Expressions, the legacy syntax used by `sed` and `grep` without `-E`). BRE is the default and probably not what you want.

Comment: Most of the time I will just match certain strings, and I can use 0 as my flag. I should notice this before using it, thanks!

Comment: @LingboTang If I'm reading the `re_format` manpage right, your regex should still have worked... but they didn't when I tested it. For what it's worth though, with POSIX regex you can still use `\\{min,max\\}` in place of `?`, `*` and `+` like so: `"[+-]\\{0,1\\}[0-9]\\{0,\\}\\.\\{0,1\\}[0-9]\\{1,\\}"` (monstrous, I know ;])

Comment: That's more trouble some, I'll just let the flag to handle the complexity for me.

Comment: @Siguza: That's a useful trick to know for using `sed`, but in modern applications you just want `REG_EXTENDED`.

Comment: @R.. Oh sure, I'm not debating that. :P